# How do I display verification of propositional logic in this way?

Tags: amsmath, logic

I want to typeset something like the following picture.

[image]

I came up with

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    &\neg&(P &\wedge&R)\\
    &T&&F&\\
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

How can I typeset a table like the above one?

Comment: Do you have to do lots of these? Are you teaching this or learning it?

Comment: I have some examples of that table on a logic textbook. And, I'm learning to typeset solutions to textbook problems.

Comment: this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162618/4686) is about generating (automatically computed) truth tables with `0` and `1`'s. Going to `T` and `F` isn't a problem, but what is more serious is that you are assigning truth values to sub-expressions. A modification of the `\xintexpr` parser, dealing with sequences of `T`'s` and `F`'s could do it, but would be a bit of overkill, as it would allow permissive `P 'and' Q 'or' 'not' R 'and' S` or parentheses arising from expansion. With a stricter input syntax such as `(P and Q) or (not(R) and S)` it is much easier, (_continued_)

Comment: and with input such as `(\P\AND\Q)\OR(\NOT(\R)\AND\S)` then it would be almost a breeze. (especially if we do not insist on treating it completely expandably).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logic is not all that well supported in LaTeX, unfortunately. At least, if it is, I haven't managed to track down the support. Everything always seems to involve a solution intended for some other problem and making it do something else.

If you have the patience, you could use something like this. I find `tabular` less hassle than a maths environment because all the Ts and Fs and Ps and Qs and so on need to be in what is essentially a text font anyway. (At least if your text font is also used for operators and so on in maths mode, which is usual.) And switching into maths mode for other things is less of a pain than typing `\text{}` all the time for text mode.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}|r@{}ccc@{\thinspace}r@{}*{3}{c}@{\thinspace}c@{}lcr@{}*{3}{c}@{\thinspace}c@{\thinspace}c@{}l}
  P&Q&R&S&$(\{$&S&$\land$&$\lnot$&$($&Q &$\land$& $\lnot$&P&$)\}$&$\lor$&$\{$&R&$\lor$&$\lnot$&$\lnot$&Q&$\})$\\\hline
  T&F&F&F& &F&F&T&& F&F&F&T &&F &&F&F&F&T&F\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: truth table line]

There are scripts which will produce the tables for you, but if you are learning logic, that's no good because you need to figure out the tables for yourself. If you are teaching logic, on the other hand, they can be very useful. They don't do the spacing adjustments I included here, either. At least, the one I used didn't.

Comment: Is there a program that has better logic support?

Comment: @crocket Not that I know of. People either do something hackish with Word or something hackish with LaTeX. At least the latter looks better. But if you find something, do post an answer!

Comment: @crocket Are you aware of [this site](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/)?

Comment: No, I wasn't. I'll take a look.

Comment: about automatic generation, does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162618/4686 help ?

Comment: @jfbu I think the automated scripts are not useful here because the OP is learning logic, as I understand it, and you don't want a script to generate the *values* if you are learning. You just want a way to typeset your own answers neatly. I used a script when I was *teaching* logic because I don't, frankly, need further practise on truth-tables. That's why I asked initially about the OP's project because what is good if you are teaching it isn't necessarily good if you're learning it. (Of course, it would be good if a script also generated a neat result.)

Answer (score 12):

You can type in the truth table with a rather natural syntax, provided some work behind the scenes is done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\truthtable}{mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \crocket_truth_make_preamble:n { #1 }
  \crocket_truth_make_body:n { #2 }
  \crocket_truth_make:
  \group_end:
 }

% variables
\tl_new:N \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl
\tl_new:N \l__crocket_truth_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__crocket_truth_body_tl
\seq_new:N \l__crocket_truth_rows_seq

% internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \crocket_truth_make_preamble:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l__crocket_truth_first_tl
  % examine the first argument in order to build the table
  % preamble and the first row
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_if_in:VnTF \c_crocket_truth_delims_tl { ##1 }
     {% a delimiter is inserted in @{...} as a phantom (almost)
      % and not taken into account for the first row
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl { @{ \__crocket_truth_delim:n {##1} } }
     }
     {
      \tl_if_eq:nnTF { | } { ##1 }
       {% vertical bar is ignored in the rows, but it gives a | in
        % the table preamble (actually, quad | quad)
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl { @{\hspace{1em}}|@{\hspace{1em}} }
       }
       {% otherwise, c is added to the table preamble and
        % the item to the first row
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl { c }
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_first_tl { ##1 & }
       }
     }
   }
  % since rows will end with &, we add a dummy trailing column
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl { c } % empty last column
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \crocket_truth_make_body:n
 {% start building the table body
  \tl_clear:N \l__crocket_truth_body_tl
  % split the argument at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__crocket_truth_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % and map it
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__crocket_truth_rows_seq
   {% each item is a row; map it to add &
    \tl_map_inline:nn { ##1 }
     {% but ignoring |
      \tl_if_eq:nnF { | } { ####1 }
       {
        \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_body_tl { \crocket_truth_tf:n { ####1 } & }
       }
     }
    % append the row terminator
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__crocket_truth_body_tl { \\ }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \crocket_truth_make:
 {% make the table
  \exp_args:NnV \begin {array} \l__crocket_truth_preamble_tl
  % temporary define \__crocket_truth_delim:n to produce its argument
  \noalign { \cs_gset_eq:NN \__crocket_truth_delim:n \use:n }
  % output the first row
  \tl_use:N \l__crocket_truth_first_tl \\
  \hline
  % make \__crocket_truth_delim:n to deliver a phantom
  \noalign { \cs_gset_eq:NN \__crocket_truth_delim:n \hphantom }
  \tl_use:N \l__crocket_truth_body_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \crocket_truth_tf:n { \makebox[1.2em]{ $ \mathrm { #1 }$ } }

\tl_const:Nn \c_crocket_truth_delims_tl { ()[]\{\} }

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\[
\truthtable{
  P Q | (P \land Q)\lor P
}{
  T T | T T T T T\\
  T F | T F F T T
}
\]

\[
\truthtable{
  P Q R S | (\{ S \land \lnot ( Q \land \lnot P )\} \lor \{ R \lor \lnot \lnot Q \})
}{
  T F F F | F F T F F F T F F F F T F\\
  T F F F | F F T F F F T F F F F T F\\
  T F F F | F F T F F F T F F F F T F\\
  T F F F | F F T F F F T F F F F T F
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice: this should be a package. Though the P Q etc. shouldn't be in italics. At least, upright is the convention in logic text books.

Comment: The document is nice, but the preamble causes vertigo.

Comment: @crocket I'll add some explanations

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. You write the logic values immediately after the operator:

```
\def\use#1#2{\kern-1.2pt
  {\kern2pt#1\kern2pt\over{\ifx^#2^\else\rm\ifcase#2 F\or T\fi\fi}}\kern-1.2pt }
\def\n#1{\use #1{}}                   
\def\P#1{\use P#1}  \def\Q#1{\use Q#1} \def\R#1{\use R#1}  \def\S#1{\use S#1}
\def\formula{\use{}{}\vrule\use{}{}}
\def\And#1{\use \wedge#1} \def\Or#1{\use \vee#1}  \def\Not#1{\use\neg#1}

$$
\P1 \Q0 \R0 \S0
\formula
\n(\n\{ \S0 \And0 \Not1 \n(\Q0 \And0 \Not0 \P1 \n)\n\}
\Or0 
\n\{ \R0 \Or0 \Not0 \Not1 \Q0 \n\}\n)
$$

\bye
```