# Center Column Values Beneath Multicolumn Header

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to recreate this table:
[image]

How do I align all the truth values beneath these headers as such? My current code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|cccccc} \hline
$p$ & $q$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{${\sim}(p\land{q})$} & $\Leftrightarrow$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$[({\sim}p)\lor({\sim}q)]$} \\ \hline
T & T & F & T & T & F & F & F \\
T & F & T & F & T & F & T & T \\
F & T & T & F & T & T & T & F \\
F & F & T & F & T & T & T & T \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

It appears that every column is centered but not evenly split between the headings.

**As a bonus question:** Also looking to generate that box around the `\iff` column but haven't researched to find an answer for that yet.

Comment: Side note: `\ttfamily` is a macro without an argument -- `\ttfamily{}` would not delimit the font change to the table only. Most likely, you meant `{\ttfamily...}`

Comment: You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286908/4427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\multicolumn`, I have created a `tabular` of `tabular`s, so it's easy to have the columns/subtables centered and the one framed.

I've also done some adjustment with `\rule{0pt}{8ex}` and a fake row to have the frame separated from the `\hline`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
{\ttfamily%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|ccc} 
\hline
$p$ & $q$ & ${\sim}(p\land{q})$ & $\Leftrightarrow$ & $[({\sim}p)\lor({\sim}q)]$ \\ 
\hline
\rule{0pt}{8ex}% to separate the framed column from the \hline
\begin{tabular}{@{}b{1em}@{}}
            T\\
            T\\
            F\\
            F\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
T\\
F\\
T\\
F\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
F & T\\
T & F\\
T & F\\
T & F\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
T\\
T\\
T\\
T\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
F & F & F \\
F & T & T \\
T & T & F \\
T & T & T \\
\end{tabular}\\[-2.5ex]
&&&&\\%fake row to separate the framed column from the \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}%end \ttfamily effect
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect and exactly what I was looking. There was a previous answer that was good as well but this answer is to the T, exactly what I was trying to attain. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer! Christian Hupfer deleted his answer, I don't know why, maybe because the framed column was missing. However it was good as well, as you said.