# What's the difference between XeLaTeX and XeTeX?

Tags: xetex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am new to TeX. Should I use LaTeX, XeLaTeX, …?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex)

Can't find any information or i don't know where to search. Anyone can explain, please?

Comment: Do you know the difference between TeX and LaTeX? Look at [i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex)

Comment: If you are having problems with the very basic concepts around TeX, then reading the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes) can also help.