# Monotype Garamond

Tags: fonts, garamond

I'm relatively new LaTeX user, and I want to use **Monotype Garamond** in LaTeX documents, at any cost. I know this is not the original version of Garamond, that the author is Jean Jannon from 1615 year, etc. For a long time I used Monotype Garamond in MS Word, and my faculty requires exclusively this font for my Ph.D. thesis, so please can anyone help me? I use **TeX Live 2013** with **WinEdt 8.0** on 64-bit machine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). You can use [XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42628/i-am-new-to-tex-should-i-use-latex-xelatex) to enable use of the system's fonts. Also you can use the `garamondx` package with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: It may be important here to know what exactly the requirement is and how they are going to check. For example, will they just look at the printed thesis? Or will they examine the pdf file properties to see which fonts are used? garamondx (install with the getnonfreefonts script) is an extension of URW GaramondNo8. The output for a basic sentence looks just like the output I get with a version of Monotype Garamond I installed for pdftex. So if they just check visually, garamondx may be "good enough". If they check the actual fonts used, maybe not. (Some places insist on PhD rules irrationally.)

Comment: I see that it is for sale. After you purchase it then it's a pretty simple matter of using it with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Once you acquire the font if you have any problems loading it then we can help you more with that.

Comment: This has also been asked on [LaTeX community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=24272)

Comment: As a completion to the comment of cfr above: If you have to decline the use of garamondx, you can either use Monotype Garamond with Xelatex or LuaLatex "out of the box". Or you use pdflatex, but that requires the installation of much more than simply the *.otf or *.ttf files on your computer. pdflatex has at least one real advantage as long as you write your thesis: it compiles a lot faster.

Comment: I can post instructions for preparing the support files for pdflatex. However, unless you have exactly the same version of the fonts as I do (2.35 regular, bold, regular italic), I cannot guarantee they will work properly without tweaking. Also, I don't know if ttf2afm is available on Windows. You need some way of getting afm files from the ttfs. (Assuming they are ttfs. If the fonts are not truetype you are out of luck - converting otf likely violates the licence and pdflatex cannot use unconverted opentype fonts.)