# Garamond is the cheapest font. How to make it as default font LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

I have just read a news about ink saving, and apparently changing font would lead to a non-negligible ink saving when printing:

http://edition.cnn.com/2014/03/27/living/student-money-saving-typeface-garamond-schools/

Given that I found it as an extremely interesting discovery, is there any method to make Garamond (which is the less ink consuming font) the default font for LaTeX? How to do that? I use both TexLive for both Win7 and Mac. My front-end editors are TexWorks and TexSHop, respectively.

Comment: IMO, this is a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168820/suggest-for-fonts-that-improve-the-usage-of-paper-as-alternative-to-times-new-ro
 I think it's very important to read http://www.thomasphinney.com/2014/03/saving-400m-font/ before pursuing this matter as proposed by http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1973/philippe-goutet

Comment: I've found that `\usepackage{xcolor}\color{white}` in the preamble also saves much ink ;^)

Comment: Ok, I apologize. I have searched a bit before posting (I was mainly searching saving, fonts, Garamond, etc.) but I haven't seen that post. Therefore, if possible, this thread can be closed.

Comment: @georgd While the two questions are clearly related, this one asks a specific question as to how to implement a font.  Maybe `\usepackage{garamondx}` as indicated in a comment at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150628/monotype-garamond

Comment: Also the `ebgaramond` package, as mentioned in the accepted answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60098/eb-garamond-on-latex. See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59403/15925

Comment: `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}` allows using URW Garamond No8 for maths (and text of course).

Comment: I haven't checked but I would be very surprised, in any case, if the comparison involved the default fonts in TeX. So there is no reason to think Garamond would take less ink if used as the default in TeX documents, even if it were true that it would if set as the default for Word documents.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the question asks for a solution to the same probably doubtful problem, therefore I think it’s a duplicate. But I won’t insist on it.

Comment: Too bad that this young guy does not know TeX. Otherwise he would perhaps have suggested Kp-Fonts in light mode, `\usepackage[light]{kpfonts}`.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is no single or unique ‘Garamond’ font as such, but for the historical fonts cut by Claude Garamont (1499-1561). However, there is a whole bunch of Garamond-looking fonts, some based on the work of Jean Jannon (1580-1658).

That said, the `mathdesign` package allows for typing both maths and text with `URW Garamond N°8`: just add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign} or \usepackage{ugm}
```

It can be complemented with the `garamondx` package, which adds true smallcaps, oldstyle figures and the f-ligatures to the `ugm` set of fonts.

The `newtxmath` package has a `garamondx` option to use the math italics part of the garamondx package.

Another beautiful font available for (pdf)LaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX is `ebgaramond`, redesigned from a historical specimen that shows a Garamont roman font and a Jannon italic font at different sizes. It exists in Opentype and Type 1 formats, but it has no bold version for the moment (hence a cheaper printing!). It has been complemented a few days ago by an `ebgaramond-maths` package that works with `newtxmath`.