# Define variables holding a percentage

Tags: macros, packages, calculations

I would like to define some variables in a tex document. For example, I write in `.tex` something similar as: `Our tool succeeds to validate x samples out of all the y samples, thus its success ratio is z`. Where `z` is defined as `x/y`, and `x` (resp. `y`) is instanced somewhere else by a number, eg., `30` (resp. `47`). As a result, after the compilation the text turns out to be `Our tool succeeds to validate 30 samples out of all the 47 samples, thus its success ratio is 63.8%`.

The advantage of this, is that I just need to change the value of some variables, to change all the numbers in the text... The difficulty is that `z` holds a percentage number.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: This appears to be a follow-up to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175413/21344) (additional requirements: floating-point arithmetic and some modifications for the percent symbol).

Comment: PythonTeX or LuaTeX can do that. See [here][1] for examples.


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115109/calculate-prices/115248#115248

Comment: @PaulGessler Yes...

Comment: @PredragPunosevac I tried your `\directlua{tex.print(string.format("%.2f",2*(1234.56+9786.45)))}`, but the compilation raised one error `Undefined control sequence`...

Comment: @SoftTimur I asked if you needed non integer values last time, and you said no:-)

Comment: @PredragPunosevac classic tex can do it as well of course:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well, i became greedy :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was assuming he will go for non integer values and want to do some computations with it which of course also can be done in TeX but with little bit work to implement floating point arithmetics.

Comment: @SoftTimur `\directlua` is a luatex primitive so you would be restricted to lualatex in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image: success rate]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xintfrac}

\newcommand\x{30}
\newcommand\y{47}


\newcommand\mypercent[3][1]{\xintRound {#1}{\xintE{#2/#3}{2}}\%}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

Our tool succeeds to validate \x\ samples out of all the \y\ samples, thus its
success ratio is  
\mypercent{\x}{\y}.

Our competitor validated only 1 sample out of 31. Her success ratio is thus
\mypercent{1}{31}, or, more precisely \mypercent [3]{1}{31}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\x{30}
\newcommand\y{47}


\newcommand\mypercent[2]{%
\expandafter\myadddot\the\numexpr 10000*(#1)/(#2)\relax\relax\%}

\def\myadddot#1#2#3{%
\ifx\relax#3%
.#1%
\else
#1\expandafter\myadddot\fi
#2#3}

\begin{document}


Our tool succeeds to validate \x\ samples out of all the \y\ samples, thus its success ratio is 
\mypercent{\x}{\y}


\end{document}
```

or for 1dp

```
\newcommand\mypercent[2]{%
\expandafter\adddot\the\numexpr 1000*(#1)/(#2)\relax\relax\%}

\def\adddot#1#2{%
\ifx\relax#2%
.#1%
\else
#1\expandafter\adddot\fi
#2}
```

Comment: `\adddot` is used by `biblatex`.

Comment: @egreg a no doubt true but unrelated observation:-)

Comment: code fails in case of `0%` validation or for example with `1/3000` success rate `;-)`

Comment: Actually i always need 1 decimal digit after `.` (eg., `%63.8` instead of `63.83`), could you show me how to change your code?

Comment: @SoftTimur answer updated

Answer (score 3):

Yo can also use `pgf` math engine:

[image]

### Notes:

- The optional first parameter can be used to control the number of decimal digits displayed -- defaults to 2 digits if not specified.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\x{30}
\newcommand\y{47}


\newcommand{\MyPercent}[3][2]{%
    \pgfmathparse{100*#2/#3}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=#1]{\pgfmathresult}\%%
}%


\begin{document}

Our tool succeeds to validate \x\ samples out of all the \y\ samples, thus its success ratio is 
\MyPercent{\x}{\y}, or with more digits \MyPercent[5]{\x}{\y}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The mandatory solution with `expl3`; the optional argument is the number of decimal digits (default 0); the result is rounded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\mypercent{O{0}mm}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round ( 100 * #2/#3 , #1 ) } \%
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\x{30}
\newcommand\y{47}

\begin{document}

Our tool succeeds to validate \x\ samples out of all the \y\ samples, thus its
success ratio is
\mypercent{\x}{\y}.

Our competitor validated only 1 sample out of 31. Her success ratio is thus
\mypercent{1}{31}, or, more precisely \mypercent [3]{1}{31}.

\end{document}
```

[image]