# Beginner issues about custom class files

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am trying to write my first ugly .cls for LaTeX related to the following  [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41545/automatic-document-update/57395#57395) which Mike and me are trying to solve (we will post soon the link to Github for people who are interested to work with us). I have two baby questions which probably can be easily answered by reading the documentation but I would like to get at least some push.

First question is about `multicolumn` environment. This snippet of code

```
\RequirePackage{multicol}
% Two-column lists (itemize, description, etc.)
\SetEnumitemKey{twocol}{
itemsep=1\itemsep,
parsep=1\parsep,
before=\raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
after=\end{multicols}}
```

is just not working for me. The second question is how I can pass options to `hyperref`

```
\RequirePackage{color}
%\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{hyperref}
%\ProcessOptions\relax
%\hypersetup{colorlinks}
%\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
%\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
%\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks,
%linkcolor=darkblue,
%filecolor=darkgreen,
%urlcolor=darkred,
%citecolor=darkblue}}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

I made some experiments based on the answers found on TeX.SE but I was not able to change the default behavior.

**News:** The further development of [Syllabus-Generator](https://github.com/ppunosevac/Syllabus-Generator)
is moved to GitHub for people who are curious and have any desire to help at least with advices. If you would like a write access please send me an e-mail.

Comment: The `\DeclareOption` bit seems to be completely out of place. However it's impossible to give advice with such limited snippets of code.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for your prompt respond. I am trying to upload files into GitHub project which Mike created for us. As soon as I do it I will send you the link so that you can check out the code. At this point cutting and pasting code into the browser is just a waist of time.

Comment: @egreg Moved to GitHub. Please see the link I posted. If you need write access just let me know your GitHub username via private e-mail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest to use a package like keyval or xkeyval or kvoptions or pgfkeys etc. to provide user options. In this way you can define a key `hyperref` which will pass all options to the package.